# Flash AS3 MovieClip Code Not Running

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip

I've done this a million times already, yet for some reason it refuses to work now.

I've made a MovieClip of an electric wire with 3 different keyframes with a few frames between each. The first 2 keyframes have a single bitmap in each with a different picture, I want it to cycle between these two to make it look like the electricity is moving and not just sitting there. The 3rd keyframe has nothing, eventually I will put an image with the electricity off, so the player can walk through, I just haven't done it yet. Since I don't want it to run the last keyframe until the player turns it off, I put a gotoAndPlay(); command in the movie clip after the second frame looping it back to the first frame, problem is, the line refuses to work. I have copied and pasted it from other programs where it worked, I have checked the Frame Name, I put other lines in there, like stop(); trace(); and other things, but could not get ANY line of code to work in the MovieClip. There's probably something like "the layer is invisible, code will not run", but I can't tell what it is. I've deleted the symbol and started over, same problem. I've restarted Flash, same problem. I've restarted the computer, same problem. I even took it to a different computer, same problem. I don't know why it won't run this code, is there something disabling it that I overlooked? I have other code in the main timeline outside the movie clip and code in other movieclips that has always worked fine and continues to work fine, I don't see what the problem is.

I ignored the problem for a while, and worked on other things, but I had to add multiple frames to an existing movieclip (which I believe was created before the other one), and now this movieclip is having the same problem. Does anyone know how to fix this, before it spreads to the rest?

I would post some code, but there really isn't any considering it's only one or two lines I need to work, and I can really copy and paste the MovieClip in here.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try some simple debugging and tell me what happens. ie put trace(currentFrame) on each of the frames in your MovieClip and see if there's any output.

Comment: Nothing. It doesn't output anything, whether I put in currentFrame, or "ahfboaidnbah". It won't do anything.

Comment: That's really odd. I'll answer with a solution that I would use, but it is pretty heavy for something this simple. Moment.

Comment: Is it possible that you could post a fla with this core issue ? I know the answer solves this, but would be nice to have a conclusive "what was wrong". Also, do you reference the movieclip instance in code anwhere, besides on it's own timeline in the movieclip itself ?

Comment: This is in the final stages of the project, the .fla is I think 10 MB right now, and just explaining where to go to see the problem would relegate another question on this site. And I don't really know what caused the problem, only that his roundabout way worked, I can't really explain what the source was. And the MovieClip was not directly refrenced in the main timeline when the problem arose. I just dragged it onto the screen, since it was purely decorative. Since I had to turn it off though, I did have a gotoAndStop(); command, but that was after the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extremely odd, though you could use this as the base class for your MovieClip which should work a treat:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Elec extends MovieClip
    {
        // vars
        private var _prevFrame:uint = 1;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function Elec()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handle);
        }

        /**
         * Event.ENTER_FRAME
         */
        private function _handle(e:Event):void
        {
            if(_prevFrame == 2) gotoAndPlay(1);

            _prevFrame = currentFrame;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that actually worked. Seems like an extremely roundabout way of doing it, but the important this is did work a treat. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, cool stuff on your site. Pretty cool games you got there.

Comment: Haha, they are extremely old.. Wish I had the time to make something more.